# Can I remove an element from an array in php if part of its name exists?

Tags: php, arrays

I currently have an array of file names which are taken from a directory with the following content :

```
fileOne.txt 
fileTwo.txt
fileOne_Results.txt
fileThree.txt
```

My code :

```
$index = array_search('_Results',$extension);
    if($index !== FALSE) {
    unset($extension[$index]);
    print_r($extension);
}
```

I'm currently looping through the directory and displaying the files in a table but I don't want to show the files that have '_Results' in their name.

Is this possible?

Ideally I'm looking to remove them from the array, I've tried the unset method but that only caters to the full file name.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the check inside the loop with `strpos`.

Comment: Use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to check if _Results is part of the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or for an alternatively you can use [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) with the following regex `(_Results)` like as

```
$array = array('fileOne.txt','fileTwo.txt','fileOne_Results.txt','fileThree.txt');
$result = preg_grep("/(_Results)/",$array,PREG_GREP_INVERT);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => fileOne.txt
    [1] => fileTwo.txt
    [3] => fileThree.txt
)
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you

Comment: I have to earn more reputation before I can do it! I'll do it once I have it though, Thanks again!

Comment: @user [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for that. And the callback can look something like this:

```
function showFile($file) {
  return strpos($file, "_Results") < 0;
}

$new_array = array_filter($old_array, 'showFile')
```